# 'No Database Selected' error when using "insert into' query

Tags: mysql

When I enter this query:

```
INSERT INTO finger-dodge-statistics.activity-open-statistics VALUES (1432147064950,0,3,'com.edr.MainActivity');
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

Comment: I doubt it's the query that's causing the problem.  What is the larger context of the code in which you execute the query?  How do you connect to the database?

Comment: I'm wondering why is JAVA tagged in this ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the database to use:

```
USE database_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to select a specific database. In a script you'd do something like this:

```
USE <database_name>;

INSERT INTO finger-dodge-statistics.activity-open-statistics VALUES (1432147064950,0,3,'com.edr.MainActivity');
```

But if you're using it from a Java program then the library/driver you are using to connect to MySQL should have a way to specify the default database.

If you post the name of the library you are using I may be able to provide a more specific explanation.

### Edit

You can specify the database name in the connection URL you specify to the DriverManager. Like so:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name
```

Where `database_name` can be replaced with your database name. You can see further detail in [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html#drivermanager).

Comment: I am using mysql connector 5.1.35 in java.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your schema and table name effectively have special characters, try delimiting them this:

```
INSERT INTO `finger-dodge-statistics`.`activity-open-statistics` 
   VALUES (1432147064950,0,3,'com.edr.MainActivity');
```